# JQuery create a form and add elements to it programmatically

Tags: jquery

Hi I need to create a form and add elements to it programatically.

```
$form = $("<form></form>");
$form.append("<input type=button value=button");
```

this doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: of course it doesn't. You didn't add a valid element in the second line.

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The 2nd line should be written as:

```
$form.append('<input type="button" value="button">');
```

Comment: No it shouldn't... Use quotes properly! `.append('<input type="button" value="button" />');`

Comment: Confirmed, the suggestion below should be added to this answer. If you don't append thew form to the body it won't submit on Firefox v40.0.3.

Comment: I removed the closing slash. `input` elements don't admit `content`.

Answer (score 52):

You need to append `form` itself to `body` too:

```
$form = $("<form></form>");
$form.append('<input type="button" value="button">');
$('body').append($form);
```

Answer (score 28):

```
var form = $("<form/>", 
                 { action:'/myaction' }
            );
form.append( 
    $("<input>", 
         { type:'text', 
           placeholder:'Keywords', 
           name:'keyword', 
           style:'width:65%' }
     )
);

form.append( 
     $("<input>", 
          { type:'submit', 
            value:'Search', 
            style:'width:30%' }
       )
);

$("#someDivId").append(form);
```

Comment: this looks like javascript, the best way to do it, however should be using html markup and after that javascript

Comment: @decebal - `this looks like javascript` -- The jQuery library on top of JavaScript.  And it is building html markup, then injecting it into the html document on the fly.  And that is the point of the OP - to do as much as possible in jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

```
function setValToAssessment(id)
{

     $.getJSON("<?= URL.$param->module."/".$param->controller?>/setvalue",{id: id}, function(response)
     {
        var form = $('<form></form>').attr("id",'hiddenForm' ).attr("name", 'hiddenForm'); 
         $.each(response,function(key,value){
            $("<input type='text' value='"+value+"' >")
 .attr("id", key)
 .attr("name", key)
 .appendTo("form");


             });
              $('#hiddenForm').appendTo('body').submit();

        // window.location.href = "<?=URL.$param->module?>/assessment";
    });

}
```

Comment: Need to remove double quotes from `.appendTo("form");`. it should be `appendTo(form); `

Answer (score 5):

The tag is not closed:

```
$form.append("<input type=button value=button");
```

Should be:

```
$form.append('<input type="button" value="button">');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Jquery

Rather than creating temp variables it can be written in a continuous flow pattern as follows:

```
$('<form/>', { action: url, method: 'POST' }).append(
    $('<input>', {type: 'hidden', id: 'id_field_1', name: 'name_field_1', value: val_field_1}),
    $('<input>', {type: 'hidden', id: 'id_field_2', name: 'name_field_2', value: val_field_2}),
).appendTo('body').submit();
```

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question, but this question appears to be the most relevant for this answer. So I will not repost it in the other similar question.

Comment: This is the best option IMHO however, you need to create the form with $('<form/>', ...).

Comment: Thanks, not really sure how one would go about this without the $('<form/>, and the other options seemed to require more syntax.

Comment: the answer originally had $('</form>', ....) which doesn't work and so I edited your answer to correct it (I should have stated this).