# HTML5 - append a form

Tags: javascript, html

I want to a generate a form in JavaScript and append the form, but it does not work:

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u35TJ/)

JS

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("part_num", "123ABC"); 
formData.append("part_price", 7.95);
formData.append("part_image", somefile)

document.getElementById("form").append(formaData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are misusing the `FormData` object.

See how to use it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects).

It is used to send data to the server, not to build forms on the client.

See how you should do it [this](http://runnable.com/UgMdmqspu4chAAAf/how-to-create-form-using-jquery-ui).

Answer (score 0):

This question at SO: [JQuery create a form and add elements to it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497140/jquery-create-a-form-and-add-elements-to-it-programmatically)
or use [jFormer](http://www.jformer.com/)